# Can someone explain what I am doing wrong with my Matrix Multiply

Tags: java, matrix, printing

I am making a program that takes two matrices and sets their value from -2 to 2. It then adds both of them together and outputs that. I have been trying to get my multiply method to work and I have not been able to. It just prints the wrong values. Can someone please explain why I am having this issue.

My code:

```
public class TwoDStuff {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] D = new int[10][10];
    int[][] E = new int[10][10];
    int[][] F = new int[10][10];

    loadMatrix(D);
    loadMatrix(E);

    System.out.println("Matrix One:");
    printMatrix(D, 3);
    System.out.println("Matrix two:");
    printMatrix(E, 3);

    System.out.println("Matrix one and two added together value:");
    addMatrix(D, E, F, 3);
    printMatrix(F, 3);

    System.out.println("Matrix one and two multiplied together value:");
    multMatrix(D, E, F, 3);
    printMatrix(F, 3);
}

public static void loadMatrix(int[][] A) {
    for (int Row = 0; Row < A.length; Row++) {
        for (int Col = 0; Col < A.length; Col++) {
            A[Row][Col] = (int) ((Math.random() * 6 - 3));
        }
    }
}

public static void printMatrix(int[][] A, int n) {
    System.out.println();
    for (int Row = 1; Row <= n; Row++) {
        for (int Col = 1; Col <= n; Col++) {
            System.out.print(Format.rightAlign(6, A[Row][Col]));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
}

public static int addMatrix(int[][] A, int[][] B, int[][] C, int n) {
    System.out.println();
    for (int Row = 0; Row <= n; Row++) {
        for (int Col = 0; Col <= n; Col++) {
            C[Row][Col] = A[Row][Col] + B[Row][Col];

        }

    }
    return n;
}

public static int multMatrix(int[][] A, int[][] B, int[][] C, int n) {

    for (int Row = 0; Row <= n; Row++) {
        for (int Col = 0; Col <= n; Col++) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
                C[Row][Col] = C[Row][Col] + A[Row][i] * B[i][Col];
            }
        }

    }
    return n;
}
}
```

Here is an example of the output I get:

```
Matrix One:

 2    -1    -1
 0    -1     0
-1    -1    -1
```

Matrix two:

```
 1     0     1
 0     0    -1
-1     0    -1
```

Matrix one and two added together value:

```
 3    -1     0
 0    -1    -1
-2    -1    -2
```

Matrix one and two multiplied together value:

```
 6    -1     4
 0    -1     0
-2    -1    -1
```

The multiplication answer should be:

```
3     0      4
0     0      1
0     0      1
```

Comment: How do you know that the result is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you could show us what output you expect and what output you actually get for `multMatrix()`.

Comment: @dave I know the result was wrong because I calculated it. Give me a min to run it again and then calculate the answer I should get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrices printed and the matrices multiplies are different. Check `for` loop initialization in two methods, `printMatrix` and `multMatrix`. Also note that Array indexes start at 0. Change value to 10, you will see exception.

Comment: Even when I change the printMatrix for loop to 0 I am still getting the wrong answer. Can you please elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: Your `for` loops iterate from `0` up to and including `n` (you use `<=`). So when you pass in the value of `3` for `n`, you are actually performing your operations on matrices of order `4`. This is fine for addition, but is breaking for multiplication. I would change *all* your `for` loops to iterate from `0` up to `n`, eg. `for (int i=0; i<n; i++)`. Then re-try.